# При подключении к AmneziaVPN пропадает интернет

Tags: openvpn

Суть вопроса такова:
Я установил на свой халявный сервер от AlibabaCloud AmneziaVPN с протоколом OpenVPN, пробросил порт 1194 для SSL[image: самый верхний это порт для SSL]
Попробовал подключиться через приложение AmneziaVPN для Windows подключение прошло успешно, но отвалился интернет (соединение с сервером при этом не пропало).

Попробовал подключиться через OpenVPN Client аналогичная ситуация -
на сервере интернет есть, а у меня нет.

вот выхлоп OpenVPN клиента

```
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater) 64bit
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25341
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25341
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 5'
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]8.209.74.136:1194
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 UDP link local: (not bound)
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]8.209.74.136:1194
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1654463805,WAIT,,,,,,
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1654463805,AUTH,,,,,,
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]8.209.74.136:1194, sid=4582bf91 366fc246
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ChangeMe
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 VERIFY KU OK
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 Validating certificate extended key usage
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 VERIFY EKU OK
Mon Jun  6 00:16:45 2022 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=ChangeMe
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, peer certificate: 2048 bit RSA, signature: RSA-SHA256
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 [ChangeMe] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]8.209.74.136:1194
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1624
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 interactive service msg_channel=728
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 open_tun
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 tap-windows6 device [OpenVPN TAP-Windows6] opened
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.24 
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.8.0.6/255.255.255.252 on interface {6C31F4FC-F170-4512-A655-E812389CE8C0} [DHCP-serv: 10.8.0.5, lease-time: 31536000]
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 Successful ARP Flush on interface [16] {6C31F4FC-F170-4512-A655-E812389CE8C0}
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1654463806,ASSIGN_IP,,10.8.0.6,,,,
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 IPv4 MTU set to 1500 on interface 16 using service
Mon Jun  6 00:16:46 2022 Blocking outside dns using service succeeded.
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 TEST ROUTES: 2/2 succeeded len=1 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 C:\windows\system32\route.exe ADD 8.209.74.136 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.141.113
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 Route addition via service succeeded
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 C:\windows\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.8.0.5
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 Route addition via service succeeded
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 C:\windows\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.8.0.5
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 Route addition via service succeeded
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1654463811,ADD_ROUTES,,,,,,
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 C:\windows\system32\route.exe ADD 10.8.0.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.8.0.5
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 Route addition via service succeeded
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 Initialization Sequence Completed
Mon Jun  6 00:16:51 2022 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1654463811,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.8.0.6,8.209.74.136,1194,,
```

помогите пожалуйста, тыкните носом в мою ошибку

UPD: С телефона подключился, та же фигня

Comment: прочитал пару тем со схожими проблемами
говорят переключить режим с "Для всех подключений" на "Для выбранных сайтов"
итог - интернет работает, но на выбранные сайты не зайти

Comment: `Amnezia` как бы намекает, что с этим изделием-поделием что-то не так:)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему тем что удалил Амнезию и установил впн с этого репозитория

```
https://github.com/emobortnik/easy-openvpn
```